# Is there any way to show gray color to states which are not having any data in Plotly map?

Tags: matplotlib, plotly, plotly-dash, mapbox-gl

I need to show gray color to the states which do not have any data in Plotly.
Sample csv file is: (This states have data) 
[image]

States which are not having data are: (I have filled the missing values as -1 
[image]

The current plots generated are: ( I need to show gray color to the states with missing data.
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Himanshu, welcome to Stackoverflow. Please provide the code you are using so far to see what you have tried. It also simplifies to replicate your current codebase. Thank you and looking forward to help!

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is to use custom colorscale in combination with

```
import plotly.express as px

px.choropleth_mapbox
```

The following is an example on how to use custom colorscale:

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import numpy as np
import copy

import pandas as pd

# Read data from a csv
z_data = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/api_docs/mt_bruno_elevation.csv')
z=z_data.values.copy()

# Compute surface color with nan's
surfacecolor = z.copy()
surfacecolor[-10:, -10:] = np.nan

# Replace nans with -100
surfacecolor[np.isnan(surfacecolor)] = -100

# Build surface trace
data = [
    go.Surface(
        z=z,
        surfacecolor=surfacecolor,
        cmin = -5,
        cmax = 350,
        colorscale=[[0, 'gray'],
                    [0.01, 'gray'],
                    [0.01, 'blue'],
                    [1, 'red']]
    )
]

# Build layout
layout = go.Layout(
    title='Mt Bruno Elevation',
    autosize=False,
    width=500,
    height=500,
    margin=dict(
        l=65,
        r=50,
        b=65,
        t=90
    )
)
fig = go.FigureWidget(data=data, layout=layout)
fig
```

A similar question has been solved by the [plotly community forum](https://community.plotly.com/t/visually-marking-numpys-nan-as-grey/17007/2).

Please find the [plotly documentation](https://plotly.com/python/colorscales/#) on how to define custom colorscales.

Hope this solves your issue!